# Scientific notation using a variable

Tags: python

Trying to generate a decimal number using scientific notation (or [exponential notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation)), for instance:

```
1.e-2
# 0.01
```

I realised that using a variable as the exponent produces an error:

```
n = -2
1.e**n
```

> File "", line 2
>
> ```
>    1.e**n
>      ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

Now I know that I can analogously write it in the form `m × 10n`:

```
n = -2
1.*10**n
# 0.01
```

However I was wondering if there was a way around so I can ideally stick to the former notation.

Comment: You change the syntax somewhat wishfully from `#.#e#` to `#.#e**X`, which as you noted doesn't work.  I dont think you have any way to keep the exact syntax, though you could try something clever like `float(f"1e{n}")` if you wanted.

Comment: If you just want the result in scientific notation you could also do: ´f"{result:1.2e}"´

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, and there can't be. In the first case, it's a *literal* and it can be parsed in a special way. In the second case, it's *an expression*. There's no way for the language to differentiate what you mean from any normal expression.

See example grammar for how float literals are parsed. It regards older version of python, but I can't find it in the grammar of recent versions.

https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/floating.html